# Syntax Error Assigning Function Output To Postgres Variable

Tags: string, postgresql, stored-functions

I'm trying to write a migration that generate a 'sort name' for each name in a table, where the sort name is identical to the regular name except that ' is replaced with a single space, the name is converted to lowercase and the last word in the name is moved to the front. E.g "John L'Mann" becomes "Mann John L". I have written a temporary function in order to do this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION generate_sort_name(name text) RETURNS text AS $$
DECLARE
    without_quotes text;
    split_name text[];
    all_but_surname text;
BEGIN
without_quotes := (regexp_replace(name, '\''', 'g'));
split_name := (regexp_split_to_array(lower(without_quotes), '\s+'));
CASE WHEN (length(split_name) = 1) THEN RETURN split_name[1];
    ELSE
    all_but_surname := (array_to_string(split_name[1:length(split_name)-1], ' '));
    return split_name[length(split_name)] || ' ' || all_but_surname;
END
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

EDIT: Thank you for the information, I have corrected the lack of semicolons and the double quotes. Now getting syntax error at or near 'END' - I've tried with semicolons following either or both and with and without one at the end of the last 'return' line.

Comment: There are lots of issue in this code. Here are a few important ones: 1) you must terminate each command with a `;`. 2) when using double quotes, it means a column name. For a string, you must use single quotes.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS

Comment: @JGH Thank you for the corrections, I have fixed the lack of ; and the use of double-quotes but now have a different syntax error?